# Help me move Burt Reynolds Face - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jQuery moving Burt Reynolds face around on the page.

My code thus far is:

```
        function moveBurt() {
          $('.burt').animate('left' : "-=100px", 3000, 'linear');
        }
```

But this isn't working :(
**PLEASE HELP ME MOVE BURT REYNOLDS FACE!!**

Comment: jQuery is not compatible with Burt Reynolds. It's a known issue.

Comment: what's this??? Who the hell is burt reynolds? , hey! you just missed the curly braces...

Comment: @Pekka: `moveJohn()` should work then.

Comment: @jAndy yes, but then it's recommended to specify in the 1st argument *which* John (surname or IMDB reference). There are several Johns who it doesn't work with at well.

Comment: @jAndy - maybe `movePekka()` will do...

Comment: lol I did really google burt reynolds... Well, I'm not a movie fanatic...

Comment: `jQuery is not compatible with Burt Reynolds. It's a known issue` is now my MSN status :D

Comment: +1 for just the best question I've ever seen on here...

Comment: @jAndy @Reigel This question is now #1 in Google's results for `'Burt Reynolds' jQuery`! http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=jquery+%22burt+reynolds%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: @jAndy maybe he manages a comeback with this. Kind of like David Hasselhoff. I hope he remembers who he has to thank for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about -

```
function moveBurt() {
              $('.burt').animate({'left' : "-=100px"}, 3000, 'linear');
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to bharlings answer, I think you should remove the "px":

```
   $('.burt').animate({'left' : "-=100"}, 3000, 'linear');
```

because JQuery will need to do arithmic. `x.style.left -= 100px` is not correct javascript

Comment: Oh ho, but do behold the power of jQuery! http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Yes, it actually works with `px`.

Comment: I should have tested it. Thanks. I'll leave my answer as I would consider it is better style not to rely on such magic...