# How do I trim/strip the URL down to the page name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about trimming/stripping the URL down to the page name...

So: `http://www.BurtReynoldsMustache.com/whatever/whoever/apage.html`

Would become: `apage.html`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's good that the solution to this doesn't need jQuery, seeing as it's a known fact that jQuery is [not compatible with Burt Reynolds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193211/help-me-move-burt-reynolds-face-jquery).

Comment: YAY, cheers MarkRobinson

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you do not need jquery:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Edit: a good point of the possible query string:

```
// it might be from browser & / anywhere else
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.split('#').pop().split('?').pop();
var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

ok, if the location object is available, use pathname gives better result as show below, however, a url can be a string or something directly from text field or span/label. So above solution should have its place.

Comment: fails with hash and querystrings

Comment: That's fine, it's not needed in this instance - vote him back up :(

Comment: The answer is NOT fine when other people will find this solution when searching the site. This will fail for other people.

Comment: This is wrong.  Answers below from @bobince and @epascarello are correct.  Use location.pathname.  That's what it's there for.

Comment: Just wanted to say I used your answer in a slightly different context. I created a tool which allowed users to upload html (with JS and CSS) via a textarea and attach images. My JS uses jQuery to parse the html, but I needed a way to pull out all of the image names to see if I had to replace the filename (various reasons, mostly due to other functionality). I found doing the following BEFORE your code much more useful:
`.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '')`
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: good to hear that it is useful. you might want to be more careful by replace the bracket, as valid URL like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx can contain bracket itself. You might consider a solution like: "url(sadfsadf#asdf)".replace(/(?:url\()(.+?)(?:\))/, '$1')

Answer (score 12):

With `location` and any link (`<a>`) elements on the page, you get a load of properties that give you specific parts of the URL: `protocol`, `host`, `port`, `pathname`, `search` and `hash`.

You should always use these properties to extract parts of the URL in preference to hacking about with `href` and probably getting it wrong for corner cases. For example, every solution posted here so far will fail if a `?query` or `#fragment` is present. The answers from Rob and digitalFresh attempt to cope with them, but will still fail if a `/` character is present in the query string or fragment (which is valid).

Instead, simply:

```
var pagename= location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 6):

Most of the solutions here are not taking advantage of the window.location object. The location object has this wonderful thing called pathname which returns just the path, no query string, host, protocol, hash, etc.

```
var mypage = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
document.location.href.split('/').pop();
```

Edit: you probably want to get rid of the query string if there is one also:

```
document.location.href.split('/').pop().split('?').shift();
```

Edit 2: this will also ignore an anchor in the url if there is one

```
document.location.href.split('/').pop().split(/\?|#/).shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also exclude query and hash values.

```
var path = location.href;
path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
path = path.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
console.debug(path);
```

Answer (score -2):

Haven't tested so compeltely guessed, but I'm sure something like this will do :-)

```
var url = 'http://www.BurtReynoldsMustache.com/whatever/whoever/apage.html';
var page = url.split('/');
alert(page[page.length-1]);​
```

**EDIT** Tested under [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9TFL/) and it was wrong, the above code should now work :-)

Comment: That's also a nice one, but... the array index is zero based.

Comment: Fails with hash and query strings